# Mod rewrite rules for hosting multiple projects using Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have several small projects I want to host on single virtual host using Zend Framework. The structure is:

```
    apps/
        testapp1/
          application/
          index.php,
        testapp2/
          application/
          index.php
```

Document root in virtual host looks like: `DocumentRoot /var/www/apps/`

I need univeral mod_rewrite rule which will transform URLs like `/apps/testapp1/xxx` into `/apps/testapp1/index.php`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I am trying to resolve that for several hours. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If your DocumentRoot for website is `/var/www/apps/`, then I guess URLs would be `http://www.example.com/testapp1/ajax` instead of `http://www.example.com/apps/testapp1/ajax`. If so -- then you need to remove `apps/` part from these rules.
2. These rules need to be placed in your **.htaccess** into website root folder.
3. If you already have some rules there then these new rules needs to be placed in correct place as **order of rules matters**.
4. You may need to add `RewriteEngine On` line there if you do not have such yet.

This rule will rewrite `/apps/testapp1/ajax` into `/apps/testapp1/index.php`, no other URLs will be affected:

```
RewriteRule ^apps/testapp1/ajax$ /apps/testapp1/index.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

This rule will rewrite ALL URLs that end with `/ajax` into `/index.php` (e.g. `/apps/testapp1/ajax` => `/apps/testapp1/index.php` as well as `/apps/testapp2/ajax` => `/apps/testapp2/index.php`):

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/ajax$ /$1/index.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

---

**UPDATE:**

This "universal" rule will rewrite `/apps/testapp1/xxx` into `/apps/testapp1/index.php` as well as `/apps/testapp2/something` => `/apps/testapp2/index.php`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([^/\.]+)$ /$1/index.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you advice me a way of creating universal regular expression for all URLs like /testapp1/xxx? I tried 
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ /$1/index.php [NC,QSA,L] with no success.

Comment: @Dapper Dan I have updated my answer with "universal" rule which will work fine for that type of URLs